# How to get user creation timestamp in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

Team, 
how to get user creation timestamp in Redshift and RDS Postgre like Oracle ?

Thank you
kesavan

Answer (score 1):

You can query the stl_userlog table where action='create'

Comment: redshiftpocdb6=# select username,recordtime,valuntil from stl_userlog where username = 'u002';
                      username                      |         recordtime         |           valuntil
----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------
 u002                                               | 2014-07-23 14:36:11.314898 | 294277-01-09 04:00:54.775807
(1 row)