# User creation timestamp in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

we have an audit and for same purpose i need a user report, where i need user creation timestamp of all redshift users.

Reference Link : [How to get user creation timestamp in Amazon Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897914/how-to-get-user-creation-timestamp-in-amazon-redshift/44006495#44006495)

My prod cluster is having around 98 user. However system table 'stl_userlog' where action='create' dose not return any record.

I'd be really great if i get some work-around on it. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Audit logging is not enabled by default in Amazon Redshift. 

For the user activity log, you must enable the `enable_user_activity_logging` database parameter. If you enable only the audit logging feature, but not the associated parameter, the database audit logs will log information for only the connection log and user log, but not for the user activity log. The `enable_user_activity_logging` parameter is disabled (false) by default, but you can set it to true to enable the user activity log. Refer below link for more information. 
[GOTO: Default Parameter Values](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-parameter-groups.html)

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. However is there any other option apart from "user activity log"....?

Cause again with Enable Redshift DB audit logs, i'll start capturing recent logs, i won't get details of event which was committed before Enabling "user activity log".

Comment: In my knowledge, there is no provision to get exact user creation time-stamp now. That ship has sailed.

Comment: Thanks a Lot Rahul